# Ubuntu 18.04 MongoDB Error "core-dump status=6/ABRT"

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04

I am currently trying to install and use mongodb for my MEVN stack project. The install took a while to troubleshoot to say the least but, not after running sudo `systemctl start mongod` and attempting to check the status of the process using `sudo systemctl status mongod` I am getting an error. Here is a snip of the error:

```
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Mon 2020-10-19 08:49:27 MDT; 5s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 3113 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 3113 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)

Oct 19 08:49:26 aroe-Z170M-D3H systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 19 08:49:27 aroe-Z170M-D3H systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Oct 19 08:49:27 aroe-Z170M-D3H systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
~
```

Any suggestions? I've read a few posts and searched around the internet  but nothing seems to fix. Thank you!

Update, here are the logs from mongologs:

Here they are:

```
"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.807-06:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"main","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.809-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.817-06:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.817-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.817-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":4614,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"aroe-Z170M-D3H"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.817-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.817-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.817-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.818-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/var/lib/mongodb","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.818-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:54.818-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3444M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.200-06:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4671205, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.200-06:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23089,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":4671205,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":1066}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.200-06:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23090,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.200-06:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4757800, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"Got signal: 6 (Aborted).\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31431,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"BACKTRACE: {bt}","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"560D1A3D29F1","b":"560D1770A000","o":"2CC89F1","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.606","s+":"1E1"},{"a":"560D1A3D4029","b":"560D1770A000","o":"2CCA029","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"29"},{"a":"560D1A3D1886","b":"560D1770A000","o":"2CC7886","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116abruptQuitActionEiP9siginfo_tPv","s+":"66"},{"a":"7F06EE2D08A0","b":"7F06EE2BE000","o":"128A0","s":"funlockfile","s+":"50"},{"a":"7F06EDF0BF47","b":"7F06EDECD000","o":"3EF47","s":"gsignal","s+":"C7"},{"a":"7F06EDF0D8B1","b":"7F06EDECD000","o":"408B1","s":"abort","s+":"141"},{"a":"560D18612BDA","b":"560D1770A000","o":"F08BDA","s":"_ZN5mongo25fassertFailedWithLocationEiPKcj","s+":"12B"},{"a":"560D182F8F6D","b":"560D1770A000","o":"BEEF6D","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine15_openWiredTigerERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_.cold.1924","s+":"1C7"},{"a":"560D18717A8A","b":"560D1770A000","o":"100DA8A","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mmbbbb","s+":"12DA"},{"a":"560D186F59B0","b":"560D1770A000","o":"FEB9B0","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE","s+":"120"},{"a":"560D18FBB83E","b":"560D1770A000","o":"18B183E","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE","s+":"4AE"},{"a":"560D186B01E7","b":"560D1770A000","o":"FA61E7","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEPNS_14ServiceContextEi.isra.1569","s+":"3F7"},{"a":"560D186B4280","b":"560D1770A000","o":"FAA280","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"650"},{"a":"560D18622B99","b":"560D1770A000","o":"F18B99","s":"main","s+":"9"},{"a":"7F06EDEEEB97","b":"7F06EDECD000","o":"21B97","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"E7"},{"a":"560D186AF69A","b":"560D1770A000","o":"FA569A","s":"_start","s+":"2A"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"5.4.0-51-generic","version":"#56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 6 09:47:18 UTC 2020","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"560D1770A000","elfType":3,"buildId":"832AC9AE6CC5692FB33A92460CF800BB1B8C176A"},{"b":"7F06EE2BE000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0","elfType":3,"buildId":"BC3C06107774266C5F7DB3F1F380A3DA68AF90FA"},{"b":"7F06EDECD000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6","elfType":3,"buildId":"D3CF764B2F97AC3EFE366DDD07AD902FB6928FD7"}]}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D1A3D29F1","b":"560D1770A000","o":"2CC89F1","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.606","s+":"1E1"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D1A3D4029","b":"560D1770A000","o":"2CCA029","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"29"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D1A3D1886","b":"560D1770A000","o":"2CC7886","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_116abruptQuitActionEiP9siginfo_tPv","s+":"66"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F06EE2D08A0","b":"7F06EE2BE000","o":"128A0","s":"funlockfile","s+":"50"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F06EDF0BF47","b":"7F06EDECD000","o":"3EF47","s":"gsignal","s+":"C7"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F06EDF0D8B1","b":"7F06EDECD000","o":"408B1","s":"abort","s+":"141"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D18612BDA","b":"560D1770A000","o":"F08BDA","s":"_ZN5mongo25fassertFailedWithLocationEiPKcj","s+":"12B"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D182F8F6D","b":"560D1770A000","o":"BEEF6D","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine15_openWiredTigerERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_.cold.1924","s+":"1C7"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D18717A8A","b":"560D1770A000","o":"100DA8A","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mmbbbb","s+":"12DA"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D186F59B0","b":"560D1770A000","o":"FEB9B0","s":"_ZNK5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_117WiredTigerFactory6createERKNS_19StorageGlobalParamsEPKNS_21StorageEngineLockFileE","s+":"120"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D18FBB83E","b":"560D1770A000","o":"18B183E","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE","s+":"4AE"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D186B01E7","b":"560D1770A000","o":"FA61E7","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_114_initAndListenEPNS_14ServiceContextEi.isra.1569","s+":"3F7"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D186B4280","b":"560D1770A000","o":"FAA280","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111mongoDbMainEiPPcS2_","s+":"650"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D18622B99","b":"560D1770A000","o":"F18B99","s":"main","s+":"9"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F06EDEEEB97","b":"7F06EDECD000","o":"21B97","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"E7"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-19T08:56:55.235-06:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31427,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"  Frame: {frame}","attr":{"frame":{"a":"560D186AF69A","b":"560D1770A000","o":"FA569A","s":"_start","s+":"2A"}}}
```

Comment: is it possible for you to share the logs from the `mongodb.log` file

Comment: It is usually located at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: I updated the post, ty for the prompt

Comment: did you recently change your mongodb version?

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: my mongod version is 4.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier."

Logs above indicate you have to downgrade to MongoDB 4.2 or earlier

Since your existing data was created using MongoDB version <= 4.2

Try downgrading to 4.2 and see if it works.

Comment: anyway to do this without purging and rerunning commands from before? Experienced a lot of other issues before finally getting this right.

Comment: I would suggest installing mongo 4.2, backing up existing data using 4.2 and then restoring the backup on your latest mongo 4.4